# Youtube videos open in browser by default

Tags: youtube, default-applications

When I'm browsing the net using the Internet app (the default browser), youtube links open up in the browser and not in the youtube app. I don't get to choose any option like before. In Applications Manager > Internet **there are no defaults set**. I tried clearing cache & data for Internet & Youtube app but I still have this problem. Same thing with Facebook youtube links, they open in the browser, no option to have it opened in youtube...it's driving me crazy

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Jelly Bean.

Turns out this problem is also on the HTC EVO (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688866), something to do with an Apple lawsuit. If I remember correctly, **I didn't have this problem when I had Ice Cream Sandwich on.**

Also, if I long press a YT link in the browser, no option shows up to open it in the app? What gives?

Comment: What do you mean by "browsing the net using the Internet app"? What is the "internet app" you are using. Do you mean default browser?

Comment: You could try uninstalling the browser then reinstalling it? See what happens to the links in the mean time on a different browser?

Comment: Yes, the default browser.

Comment: I can't uninstall the browser, the uninstall button is grayed out.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the youtube app?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work. Seems to be a problem with Jelly Bean. Other people are having this as well... http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1892888

Comment: The links open to YouTube in the browser. If you hit Play, does that *stay* in the browser, or do you then get sent to the Youtube app? I ask because that is the behaviour that I see with Android 4.2.

Comment: This worked for me for the Android web browser: Settings -> Useful Features -> Open links in apps. For some reason mine became unchecked.

Comment: For Brave browser users, try: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244632/22600

Answer (score 8):

Try resetting app preferences. Go to **Settings**->**Apps**, choose from menu **Reset app preferences** and confirm **Reset apps**. This will reset all app preferences.

To reset preferences for specific app (e.g. Browser), choose it in **Settings**->**Apps** and press **Clear defaults** button in **Launch by default** section.

Next time you try to open YouTube video you should be asked which app to use.

These instruction were verified on pure Jelly Bean (on Galaxy Nexus).

Comment: The person asking the question noted that 'clear defaults' didn't work for him.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, here's one way to fix it: set user agent string as desktop.

To do so, type about:debug in address bar to get debug settings, then go to Settings > Debug > UA String. Set it to Desktop, restart browser and load any YT URL - it should show you the option to open YouTube app.

Tested personally on Nexus S running Android 4.2.

Comment: Thanks Sumesh, but that doesn't work either and I did everything like you said even rebooted the phone. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

FacebookLinks fix the problem of Facebook, it allow you to open youtube post from Facebook directly using Youtube app!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.obteq.sharetoyoutube

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange and thank you for your contribution! If you want some badges, fill out all of the fields in your profile and read the "About" link near the search box. Enjoy StackExchange!

Answer (score -1):

Goto Apps in Settings and clear the youtube app preferences. It will reset your data and you will be prompted to open videos.

Answer (score -1):

This really worked for me! Just follow these steps:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. Go to *Apps*
3. click on the *Google Chrome* app
4. Go down and click "clear defaults"

Your all done and the next time you click to watch a video it should give you the option to chose Youtube app.