# Embedded Youtube videos don't play in browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, youtube

I have a Samsung S4 running Android Kitkat 4.4.2 (latest version on Verizon).
Both in the Android default browser and chrome browser, when I'm on a page with an embedded Youtube video (all pages with embedded youtube videos), the video doesn't play inside the page. It launches the Youtube APP instead. With my Firefox mobile browser, I don't see a still of the video, instead I get the error that a plug in is required to display content.
All of this just recently happened, so I probably messed up a setting or something related to the Youtube APP itself. Unfortunately since the Youtube app is native to my phone, I can't try uninstalling and reinstalling.
Looking for some advice on how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Can you go to `Settings>More>Application manager>Youtube` and try clicking on `Clear Defaults`, failing that try the same in Google Chrome and / or Google Search. Each has their own record of the default application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube videos open in browser by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34873/youtube-videos-open-in-browser-by-default)